# How to change the order of the subcategory and category in a post?

Tags: categories, order

[image: Hi, I'm trying to change how the categories and subcategories are displayed in a post. As you can see in the following image, the Category (España) is displayed before the subcategory (Valencia), but I'd like it to be displayed the other way around.]

I guess it is something simple which I'm not able to see.
Any help would be much appreciated.
Best,
M.

Comment: Checkout this plugin, [Category Order and Taxonomy Terms Order](https://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-terms-order/)

Comment: categories don't have an "order", the order they appear in is unordered, or sorted alphabetically in code, there isn't a numeric value that can be changed to influence the order they appear

Comment: And isn't there a way to display the subcategory before the category?

Comment: Display where? On the post itself? You can control that code through the theme. Or did you mean here in the admin menu?

Comment: I mean in the admin menu, because that order is the same one that is used in the blog afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a [get_the_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_the_terms/) filter to change the other the category values are returned, e.g.

```php
function sort_the_terms( $terms, $post_id, $taxonomy ) {
    if ( 'categories' === $taxonomy ) {
        usort( $terms, function( $term1, $term2 ) {
            // Better sort logic here
            return $term1->name <=> $term2->name;
        } );
    }
    return $terms;
}
add_filter( 'get_the_terms', 'sort_the_terms', 20, 3 );
```

You'll need to change the logic in the comparator to get the order you want, e.g. using information in wp_termmeta or the group or parent ID of the term. (If you're using parents to build a hierarchy you might need something more complicated than just a [usort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) though, since 'place in hierarchy' is going to be difficult to determine completely in a comparator.)

Comment: Thank you, but I've tried and it doesn't work... 
I'm using parents to build the hierarchy. In this case España > Valencia, and I would like it to be displayed the other way around: first the child, second the parent.